# Can I use MLE here and what is the approximate SE?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, predictive-models, maximum-likelihood

I have got 10k data of the form `(y, x1, x2)` where `y` is the dependent variables and `x1, x2` are independent variables.

I have an existing model `M`, where `M(x1, x2)` gives the pdf of `y`. So `M(x1,x2,y)` gives the density at `y`

Now, I would like to improve the model by introducing some simple transformation of its argument, like: `M2(x1, x2) = M(a*x1 + b*x2 + e, c*x1 + d*x2 + f)`

I picked the parameters `a ~ f` based on max loglik (`sum log M2(x1, x2, y)`) of the total 10k data set.

Is this method of using MLE valid? (I don't need of cross validation at this point) it looks like nonlinear regression, seems a bit different.

What's the distribution of `a^ ~ f^` approximately? Can I find a confidence interval of each parameter so that I know if they differ from 0 or 1 so I can simplify the model?

(given `M` is continuously differentiable and I have got Jacobian and Hessian of it. Also I am able to get Jacobian and Hessian of the loglik from `M2` w.r.t. `a ~ f`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you maximized the loglikelihood of the data wrt the parameters, then yes, you've calculated an MLE. The sampling distribution of your parameters is a bit tougher to determine. You can get asymptotic confidence intervals using the [likelihood ratio test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section2/apr233.htm). Do you know what a profile likelihood is? If you calculate the profile log-likelihood of each of your parameters, then if it is well approximated by a quadratic, your parameter's sampling distribution is approximately normal, and the approximation should be good. Otherwise, I would suggest bootstrapping.